# asp.net c# Active directory slow response time

Tags: asp.net, performance, activedirectorymembership

I managed to write a custom membership provider which mix Active Directory with some features on SQL Server.
Since a month or so, using this tool I acknowledged a slow response time when I call "UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity" to retrieve some user information from AD. This response time can be roughly 5 seconds per SamAccountName, and here we speak of about 30 users on AD.

Nonetheless, the login time is blazing fast and roles querying is decent (not very speedy, but tolerable).

Domain controller and web server have the right ports enabled on firewall (although the web server is in DMZ), with no noticeable latency.

DNS resolution is fast across all the networks.

Anyone has ever encountered a similar problem?

Thanks in advance,
V.

Comment: Did you try to search with PrincipalSearcher instead?

Answer (score 0):

i can answer my own question. The problems seems to be that i overused connection on the AD.
Every action used to have a call to principalcontext which slow down everything.

Damn me and my bug :)

Thanks to everyone anyway :)